# accessing python object pointer data

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes, pyobject

I have a python `set` that contains a collection of non-hashable python objects with uniform type which I want to process.

To improve efficiency of my algorithms, I would like to interface using ctypes with an external index implementation that accepts only `uint64` as data values.

I was hoping that I could to pass pointer references to the python object into this external library as `uint64`?

I tried `ctypes.cast(ctypes.py_object(my_python_object), ctypes.c_uint64)` but am getting `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`.

Also, what about the reverse, getting a reference to a python object as `uint64` and turning it into a "real" python object?

Comment: Seriously, what's wrong with using `id()`?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Seriously nothing. :-) Just that I never realised it existed. Any chance of getting a python object from the `id()` value? If not, I could always convert my `set` into a `dict` with the ids as keys.

Comment: The thing is... If your object is dead, you cannot get it back from the `id()` - instead you will crash your interperter :D

Comment: Would tools like Cython or manually writing a small extension module to interface with the C code be an option?

Comment: What you're doing seems dubious, but you haven't provided enough details to say one way or the other. Anyway, if you're working directly on Python objects using a C library, make sure to load it as a `PyDLL` instance that holds the GIL when calling functions. Then just set the function's `argtypes`, with the Python object parameter defined as `py_object`. The C function will handle this as a `uint64_t`. Passing the object directly increments the reference count during the call, so there's no danger of the object getting deallocated on another thread.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The objects will still be alive, because they remain in the set. The index only stores some unique object id (it need not be a pointer). Hence, the `id()` function seems perfect.

Comment: @user2357112 I want to avoid cython. With the `id()` function, also it is no longer as dubious as initially. I will store the objects in a `dict` keyed by their `id()`'s. Only the `id()` values are stored and retrieved from the external index. The object gets retrieved from the dict with the id key. No messing with references, pointers, etc. - Seems very safe.

Comment: @eryksun Many thanks for the advice. I am sure I will make use of it in future projects.

Comment: Why not use it now? If you have a C funtion `foo`, surely it's simpler to call `lib.foo(x)` then `lib.foo(id(x))`. You just have the one-time setup of `lib.foo.argtypes = [py_object]`.

Comment: @eryksun Indeed, but I am extending somebody else's python package by subclassing a class that already handles the ctypes part. With `id()` it will be easier to have the PR accepted because I am not touching any low-level parts of the package: my PR will be self-contained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why wouldn't you simply use the `id()` function in CPython?

```
>>> x
<object object at 0x7fd2fc742090>
>>> hex(id(x))
'0x7fd2fc742090'
```

The [CPython documentation of `id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) says that

> `id(object)`
>
> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: **This is the address of the object in memory.**

---

You also need to mess with the reference counts and such, if you're to "convert" this `uint64_t` of yours back to a Python object. As far as I know, `ctypes` do not easily let one to increase/decrease the reference counts of Python

Comment: Strictly speaking, this implementation detail could change in the future.

Comment: The very similar case of `object.__hash__` [actually has changed](http://bugs.python.org/issue5186) in the past; it no longer just returns `id(self)`. I wouldn't be entirely surprised if they ever decide to change `id`, for example, to reduce the same kind of bucket collisions that occurred with `object.__hash__`.